# Is it possible to do text search with EVE using the mongo text index?

Tags: eve

Is it possible to use text search with EVE? It's implemented on mongo https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/text-search/ but I can't run it on EVE.

i.e.

```
find( { $text: { $search: "java \"coffee shop\"" } } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The index must be created before

For example (in the settings.py):

```
'mongo_indexes' : {'text': ([('names.keyword', "text")])}
```

and then

```
localhost:5000/api/images?where={"$text": {"$search": "food dog"}}
```

Comment: Of course you can also build the index from the mongo shell. With `mongo_indexes` however, Eve will create the index on launch if it is missing, which is handy and makes sure you are always running on a properly indexed db.